# How to filter raw element value javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to textarea raw value like 123abc!@ to filter 123and abc and !@# and show in number ,symbol and string id.

```js
function getValue() {
  var all = document.getElementById( 'allText' ).value;

  all.filter = number; 
  all.filter = string;
  all.filter = symbol;   
  document.getElementById( 'number' ).innerText = all;
  document.getElementById( 'symbol' ).innerText = all;
  document.getElementById( 'string' ).innerText = all
}
```

```html
<label>Number:</label><p id="number"></p>
<label>Symbol:</label><p id="symbol"></p>
<label>String:</label><p id="string"></p>
<label>Write any:</label><textarea onkeydown="getValue()" id="allText"></textarea>
```

Comment: an assignment changes the value. please add the part of HTML you like to change and the wanted result.

Comment: <label>Number:</label><p id="number"></p>

Comment: i want just number in id number

Comment: Its not clear what you are trying to do , like what are you trying to do here:
  all.filter = number;

Comment: function getValue() {
    var all = document.getElementById('allText').value;
}    

 <label>Number:</label><p id="number"></p>
    <label>Symbol:</label><p id="symbol"></p>
    <label>String:</label><p id="string"></p>
    <label>Write any:</label>
    <textarea onkeydown="getValue()" id="allText"></textarea>

I want to textarea raw value like 123abc!@ to filter 123and abc and !@#
and show in number ,symbol and string id.

Comment: please add the missing parts to the question.

Comment: <label>number:</label><p id="number"></p>
    <label>Write any:</label>
    <textarea onkeydown="getValue()" id="allText"></textarea>

function getValue() {
    var all = document.getElementById('allText').value;
    document.getElementById('number').innerText = filter number from all and send;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) on `all` to match a subset of characters within its value. Note that `all` is a string itself, and so are all characters within it by themselves. I've also changed the event to listen to from `keydown` to [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input). Here's a working example:

```js
function getValue() {
  var all = document.getElementById( 'allText' ).value;

  document.getElementById('string').innerText = (all.match(/[a-z]/gi)  || []).join('');
  document.getElementById('number').innerText = (all.match(/\d/g)      || []).join('');
  document.getElementById('symbol').innerText = (all.match(/[^\s\w]/g) || []).join(''); 
}
```

```css
body { display: flex; }
label { font-weight: bold; }
* { text-align: left; margin: 0.5rem; }
```

```html
<div class=input>
  <label>Write any:</label><textarea oninput="getValue()" id="allText"></textarea>
</div>

<table class=output>
  <tr><th>Numeric:</th><td id="number"></td></tr>
  <tr><th>Symbol:</th><td id="symbol"></td></tr>
  <tr><th>Alpha:</th><td id="string"></td></tr>
</table>
```

### `... .join('')`

the `String.match(...)` function returns an array with all matches if some were found. For example, `"abc".match(/[a-z]/g)` would return `["a", "b", "c"]`. Hence the calls to [`... .join('')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) at the end. This concatenates all characters in the array to one single string.

### `all.match(...) || []`

If `String.match` did not find any matches, `null` is returned instead. In order to be able to call `.join` unconditionally, `null` values default to an empty array with this syntax.